# c# sessions "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an ASHX file:

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

On the line:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["loggedIn"] = true
```

Is this how I use sessions properly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would guess that `Session` is the culprit here; with reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null), you might want to try adding `: IRequiresSessionState` to your handler (the code-behind for the ashx). So you should have something like:

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState 
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        context.Session["loggedIn"] = true;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that it is easier to talk to the `context` passed in, but `HttpContext.Current` should work too.

Answer (score 4):

ASHX handlers don't have session information by default.

See this page
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingSessionStateInHttpHandlersASHXFiles.aspx

```
IRequiresSessionState
```