# How to save value in session in .net

Tags: c#, web-services

I am trying to save value in session in webservice but it gives me error: `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

```
Session["ProcessStartTime"] = strDate;
```

Comment: Make sure session state is enabled for your webservice.

Comment: You need to add support for sessions to the web service. What web service technology are you using?

Comment: In what kind of file do you use Session object?

Comment: i am using c#.net Lloyd

Comment: But what web service framework, classic SOAP services, WCF etc...?

Comment: i'm using framework 3.5 Lloyd

Comment: in .cs file i m using session. Algreat

Comment: These links can be helpful:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804954/c-sharp-sessions-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null

Answer (score 0):

Add `(EnableSession = True)` to the WebMethod

```
[WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
```

or Read this nice article on [How to use session state in web service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35119/Using-Session-State-in-a-Web-Service)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `strDate` not null
2. check you enabled session using `Session["ProcessStartTime"] = strDate;` before declaration    method

here is a sample

```
public class mytest: System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod (EnableSession = true)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
           //your logic here
            if(strDate!=null)
                  Session["ProcessStartTime"] = strDate;
            else
                 // handle if ur strDate is null
         }
    }
```