# Asynchronous function and Session State

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asynchronous, delegates

In my WebService I'm trying to call an assynchronous function using delegate. The problem is that the session is lost when the function is called. Is there anyway to keep the Session state when the asynchronous function is called?

Thanks a lot,

Rafael

Comment: Did you google it first? [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096789/asynchronous-threads-and-session)

Comment: Please excuse Daniel's snarkiness, but he did post an excellent possible duplicate.  Does that other thread answer your question?  If not, please explain why so we can help you further.