# session null on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I got an strange exception on my production server:

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>   selectie.Functie..ctor() in ..\Page\Specificaties\Functie\Functie.cs:35
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

line 35:

> Kast kast = (Kast)HttpContext.Current.Session["kast"];

The session is used in multiple webmethods like:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static String button_click(String information) {

}
```

and

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public static void ChangeKast(String id, String value)
{

}
```

in my search for a solution i found this:

> As you might expect, if you enable session support for one Web method, that does not imply that it is enabled for another Web method. In fact, the Context.Session property will be null if EnableSession is not explicitly set to True for a particular Web method.

localy it runs perfectly, and has worked since today... How could i solve this?

Comment: How is the application deployed to the production server? Is it pre-compiled?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net What to do if current session is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null)

Comment: the application is build as a deployment package and installed through import application IIS manager.

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin the application runs fine local

Comment: @Sebastiaan Correct me if I'm wrong. I guess that this code is directly or indirectly invoked from the event handler of Global.asax. Please check out this link for further reference - http://siderite.blogspot.com/2009/01/session-state-is-not-available-in.html

Answer (score 4):

Look in Web.Config on the live machine under the `<system.web>` Element there should an element called `<sessionstate>` make sure it's not set to `Mode="Off"`

```
<configuration>
...
<system.web>
....
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
....
</system.web>
....
</configuration>
```

Comment: does the edit help? You sessionstate node should look like the above, make sure the mode attribute on sessionstate is not set to Off

Comment: Just adding `<sessionState timeout="20" />` to the web.config and making sure I had enabled session in the web method `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` worked.

Answer (score 0):

My wisdom with these kind of session null scenarios says that - there are hidden errors occurring in your applications but not unearthed. any exception inside the code would kill the session and might continue with a new session so the values are null...

best approach, run your dev environment code in vs ide with debug --> exceptions menu, on all exception handlers and run through the application for several scenarios, eventually you would realize there are hidden errors starting from simple errors like convertToInt or similar reference errors, which cause session becomes null... But as I guessed things did not break at error in "error" page but found through above "DEBUG" with all exceptions ON option.

Hope it helps!
HydTechie