# Asp.net session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I have a asp.net project with c# code behind. I have a static class called GlobalVariable where I store some information, like the currently selected product for example.

However, I saw that when there are two users using the website, if one changes the selected product, if changes it for everybody. The static variables seem to be commun to everybody.

I would want to create (from the c# code) some kind of session variable used only from the c# code, but not only from the page, but from any class.

Comment: Static variables are accessed throughout your application. Sessions are used to store & access variables within a user login & logout. Use a database to have your variables outlive your sessions and application. To share data between multiple applications use a distributed cache and store your [ASP.NET Session](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/session-index.html) in a cache.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes static variables are shared by the whole application, they are in no way private to the user/session.

To access the Session object from a non-page class, you should use `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Comment: @Mathieu Remember to check for null, as Session will not always be created for every request. For example, simple handlers, like from .ashx files, are not setup by default to create the Session object.

Comment: Apropos, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null/1382811#1382811

Answer (score 13):

`GlobalVariable` is a misleading name. Whatever it's called, it shouldn't be `static` if it's per session. You can do something like this instead:

```
// store the selected product
this.Session["CurrentProductId"] = productId;
```

You shouldn't try to make the  `Session` collection globally accessible either. Rather, pass only the data you need and get / set using `Session` where appropriate.

Here's an overview on working with [session storage in ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for providing an example of how to use Session.

Answer (score 11):

You sort of answered your own question.  An answer is in session variables.  In your GlobalVariable class, you can place properties which are backed by session variables.

Example:

```
public string SelectedProductName 
{
    get { return (string)Session["SelectedProductName"]; }
    set { Session["SelectedProductName"] = value; }
}
```