# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written following code in my **global.asax** file

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        ConnStr = objConnStr.GetConnectionString();


        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["LOGIN"] != null  )

        {   
 }
}
```

It is throwing following error at **HttpContext.Current.Session["LOGIN"] **

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception** Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

what may be the issue ?

Comment: Session can be null in several cases:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please keep in mind that appreciation is shown through upvotes and accepted answers (checkmarks). If you have any questions, the [FAQ] is extremely useful, especially the [FAQ#HowToAsk] How to ask.

Answer (score 5):

This is most likely because `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null. You need to do this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null 
    && HttpContext.Current.Session["LOGIN"] != null)
```

Now, `HttpContext.Current` could be null, also. However, in almost all practical cases (especially in asp) you can make a fair assumption that it will not be null. In fact, my current version of ReSharper does not even yell about Current possibly being null. So, that is more of a side note :) Your problem is most likely from `Session`

Comment: Is `HttpContext.Current` guaranteed not to be null?

Comment: You know, I kept waffling on that one. I believe it is extremely rare that it is null, but I cannot find anything guaranteeing it. In fact, the best I can find is this article about it being null: http://odetocode.com/articles/112.aspx    I will re-update my answer

Comment: I've played around with code contracts a bit, and I've found several points in the framework where decompiling methods shows that there's no way they could return null, but yet there's no documentation of that fact (let alone a contract annotation).  I wouldn't be surprised if this is one of them, but I don't have a decompiler handy on this computer to check.

Comment: Well, it probably depends on the usage, too. Like I mentioned, in ASP, I have NEVER heard of this being null...