# casting an object with "as" still giving an error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object MyObject and I'm storing that in the session.

I write this:

```
MyObject TheObject = HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjInSession"] as MyObject;
```

I'm getting error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` Why? I thought that if you use `as` to cast and the cast produces an error then it just returns null and execution continues. How should I rewrite this line?

Thanks for your suggestions.

PS: The error is produced because I removed the enable session line `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` I'll put the line back in but I want to make sure there are no exceptions in case anything goes wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are the `Session` is triggering it (it either doesn't exist or hasn't been established). This is common in handlers if you haven't marked the class to manage sessions.

Yes, you're right, `as` will attempt a cast or result in a `null`, but that's only assuming you're left-hand object is valid and has a value to attempt a cast on.

To explain it a bit more in depth:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["Foo"]
HttpContext                         Probably fine
HttpContext.Current                 May not exist
HttpContext.Current.Session         Most likely cause (no access to session)
```

Which essentially makes referencing a key off the `Session` element impossible if `Session` itself doesn't exist.

Comment: The error is produced because I removed the enable session line [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] . Of course, I'll put the line back but why is it that the as opertor throws an error?

Comment: @frenchie: If you replace the `WebMethodAttribute` and allow the handler access you should be fine. Although I'm a firm believer in practice makes perfect; or basically "try and see for yourself". Also, given this is a webservice you should be fine just referencing the property `Session` instead of trying to access HttpContext's static member.

Comment: I'm looking to make the code safe if the session IS null or not working. In this case, there's a branch of code that exits the webservice "nicely". Bu right now, if the cast fails, it'll just throw an exception.

Comment: What do you mean by "but that's only assuming you're left-hand object is valid and has a value to attempt a cast on."

Comment: @frenchie: Have a look at [this other SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null) with regards to handling a null session. And what I mean is `as` only works when it can retrieve a value first. If it fails getting the value (i.e. `Session` is null and therefor `Session[key]` won't work) it's moot about how effective the `as` cast is. Worded differently, `as` isn't the problem (as originally implied by your question) it's `Session` that's the problem.

Comment: Ah ok, got it: if it can't access .Current.Session there's no casting at all occurring because there's nothing to access in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant "but that's only assuming you're RIGHT-hand object is valid."

Comment: @frenchie: I was using left/right in terms of the `as`, but you're right--everything past the `=` is the right-hand.