# object reference error when using with session dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ive been using the following code for the last week and its worked no problem, then for some reason this morning its throwing:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My code:

```
DataSet icanData = (DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["icanDataSession"];
if (!(icanData == null))
{
     return icanData;
}
```

The reason I'm using `HttpContext.Current.Session` is because its running in a class.

Comment: Run this code in different thread?

Comment: You will need to check `HttpContext.Current.Session == null`, not `HttpContext.Current == null`. If the session is null, that could point to other issues.

Comment: ive stopped it erroring by adding the following "if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null)" however I dont think its storing the dataset in a session any more

Comment: Which part of the page lifecycle are you doing this from? `Page_Load`?

Comment: Can you review my answer? I think it covers what you ended up doing to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check session is null before cast session object to dataset

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["icanDataSession"]=!null)
{
  DataSet icanData = (DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Session["icanDataSession"];
  if (!(icanData == null))
   {
     return icanData;
   }
}
else 
{
return new Dataset();
}
```

Comment: i havent really found a solution so i can't really accept any of the answers above

Comment: ive sorted it, it seems that if i create the instance of the dataset on the page as private it kills it. im sure your all shaking your heads now thinking "school boy" error but thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `Session["icanDataSession"];` has been lost.

Where in your code does it get set? Maybe any sessions that were originally stored in IIS have been lost via an App Pool recycle.

Comment: if its not set i populate the dataset and then at the bottom i set it just before returning the dataset

Answer (score 0):

I think, if this code is being called by an aspx.cs, then it will work fine. But if this is called by any stateless service, then it will throw error as you reported.
Better to check
if(HttpContext.Current != null)
first..

Comment: ok ive used a bit of your code and a bit of Anant Dabhi's code so i now have this line "if (HttpContext.Current != null)" however im still getting the same error

Comment: it is being called by a .aspx file, what is wierd is that it has run fine all week

Answer (score 0):

You stated you were calling `public static DataSet IcanData()` at the top of your ASPX file. Instead, call that method from your `Page_Load` event. At the point in time where you are accessing the session it won't be available.

Information on why the session can be null can be found in this question: [What should I do if the current ASP.NET session is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null)