# My Session variable is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a movie ticket reservation project. I want to get username from page1 and display it on page2 (using session variable)

Page1:

```
 string uname = TextBox1.Text;
 Session["UName"] = uname;
 Session.Timeout = 30;
```

Page2:

```
 if ((string)Session["UName"] != null)
        {
            string user = (string)Session["UName"];
        }
```

and I placed a sign out button in page2 to remove session variable value. But the session variable is always null.
I've already used cookies in the page1 and will this be a cause? or what else?  Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use masterpages?

Comment: And does TextBox1.Text actually have a value? Please past in more code....

Comment: Are you prematurely removing the `Session` on page 2?  Check that whatever function you are using to clear the session is not accidentally triggered.

Comment: I'm using master pages and I want to load the TextBox1 value to session variable at the time of submitbutton_click().

Comment: Is there any other ways to store and retrieve username other than session variable?

Comment: @user2842987 which event of which page do you set it in and which event of which page do you read it in?

Comment: I'm setting the session var value in ButtonClick event of Page1 (Submit Button) and retrieving it on the PageLoad event of Page2(To display UserName in Label Control)

Comment: @user2842987 of course you can use `querystring` but it depends upon the scope of your requirement.

Comment: @SurajSingh, You should **never** put a username in a querystring!

Comment: I wouldn't pass anything remotely related to security in a query string.  @user2842987 how do you get from Page1 to Page2?

Comment: @Liam I agree ! I just tried to give him a option he has, to pass data.

Comment: Could you please tell me any other ideas other than query string because currently I'm using query string.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer on when the Session can be null:

[What should I do if the current ASP.NET session is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null)

I personally often ran into this issue when I was using async requests with completion callback. In these callbacks I wanted to set something in the session and it was null.

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs when doing a `Response.Redirect` after setting the session variable.  You can work around this issue by calling the overload instead:

```
Response.Redirect("...", false); // false = don't stop execution

//causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline
//chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

The underlying issue is a `ThreadAbortException` which is often ignored because it doesn't break the application. This is a known issue, and you can learn more about it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629.

**Side Note**

On a side note, you shouldn't be resetting your `Session.Timeout` value in the code like that. I can't be sure, but that may also have an adverse affect on your logic. Instead, you should specify the session timeout in the `web.config` under the `system.web` section:

```
<sessionState timeout="60"  />
```

Comment: I tried it already but it's not working. I'm struggling with this issue for a long time.

Comment: @JamesJohnson This actually worked for me. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem, 
I was toggling between debugging two different sites on localhost and there were two cookies for the session ID.

I deleted the cookies via Chrome's developer tools [Press F12 in Browser]->Application->Storage->Cookies