# How to get the SessionStateBehavior for a request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I know that the `SessionState` attribute can be used to set the `SessionStateBehavior` for requests to a particular MVC controller. My question is, how can I determine the current request's `SessionStateBehavior` programatically? I see that `HttpContext` has an [internal property for this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpContext.cs,1268), but is there any way to get at this publicly?

In particular, I'd like to know whether the session state behavior was disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Session == null` will check for a disabled session
`HttpContext.Current.Session.IsReadOnly` will check for a read-only session

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this further, it seems like the only surefire solution to the exact problem posted above is to access the internal `SessionStateBehavior` property using reflection:

```
var behavior = (SessionStateBehavior)typeof(HttpContext)
    .GetProperty("SessionStateBehavior", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(HttpContext.Current);
```

However, for the specific case of checking whether session state has been disabled, in most scenarios a simple null check against `HttpContext.Current.Session` should suffice. I'm basing this on the reasons listed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/asp-net-what-to-do-if-current-session-is-null) for why that property may be null.