# Session variable is cleared before calling controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, request

I need to keep a Session variable updated at all times while a user is using the application.

I have tried the following approaches:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var a = filterContext.HttpContext.Session["SPUsers"];
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["SPUsers"] != null)
        {
            new Task(InitialiseUsers).Start();
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        var a = requestContext.HttpContext.Session["SPUsers"];
        if (requestContext.HttpContext.Session["SPUsers"] == null)
        {
            new Task(InitialiseUsers).Start();
        }
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }

    private void InitialiseUsers()
    {
        var spClient = new SPClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADVBaseUrl"]);
        Session["SPUsers"] = spClient.GetAllUsers();
    }
}
```

Where all my other controllers inherit from `MyController`.

I can see that the `OnActionExecuting` and `Initialize` methods are called when I navigate to a page, and also that the `InitialiseUsers` method is called when the `SPUsers` session variable is `null`.

The problem is, is that that session variable is **always** `null`.

Why is that?

Why does the value not get updated in `InitailiseUsers`? Or is it that the value is cleared beofre reaching the other 2 methods?

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You might find a hint to answer your query with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/what-should-i-do-if-the-current-asp-net-session-is-null

Comment: Using session implies a stateful web server. This does not scale. Generally, state is something I'd keep in a database.

Comment: @spender I am retrieving the data from a SharePoint list, but CSOM is really slow, so I want to cache that data in the session

Comment: It looks like everybody would end up with the same list of users ine session variable.  Maybe a singleton (application context or a static property) would work better for scalability.  Aside from that, are certain that spClient.GetAllUsers() isn't returning null?

Comment: @Obie Thank you Obie - static property is exactly what I need as you are right - the list of users will always be the same (its all the users!) post an answer if you like and I'll accept

Comment: Thanks @Bassie, I've been in a points drought for a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like everybody would end up with the same list of users ine session variable. Maybe a singleton (application context or a static property) would work better for scalability.