# How Can I get formData in OWIN WebAPi C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest, owin, form-data

I'm sending a request to server from POSTMAN :

[image]

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

WebApi method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace AddMobileAPI.Controllers
{

    [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/alarms")]
    public class AlarmsController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("uploadImage")]
        public IHttpActionResult UploadImageAsync()
        {

            var testValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["test"];


            return Ok("Success !!");
        }
    }
}
```

This Code give me an error at this Line

```
var testValue = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["test"];
```

because the Current is null

Comment: Please have a look at below link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382791/what-should-i-do-if-the-current-asp-net-session-is-null

Comment: How can this post help me @AnkurShah

Comment: As you are call this api using postman and this api is CORS enabled api. That might be a reason you are got this error.